# Where to place `protop.json` file?

Tags: protop

If a Github project has its `.proto` files in `src/main/proto` and is using itself as the protobuf repo, should `protop.json` also be in `src/main/proto` or at the root of the project?

When I try that in which the contents of `src/main/proto/protop.json` is:

```
{
  "name" : "foo",
  "version" : "0.1.0",
  "organization" : "bar"
}
```

and create a client project with a `protop.json` file as:

```
{
  "organization" : "foo",
  "name" : "bar-client",
  "version" : "0.1.0",
  "include" : [ "." ],
  "private": true,  
  "dependencies" : {
    "foo/bar": "git:https://github.com/foo/bar/tree/use-protop/src/main/proto"
  }
}
```

`protop sync` errors with `Could not find package foo/bar https://github.com/foo/bar/tree/use-protop/src/main/proto.`.

How should this be structured? Does `protop` force the proto files to be in a separate Github project?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind `protop` is to allow an independent release schedule for `proto` files. As such, the `proto` files belong in a separate Github project from the consumers of the `proto` files.

Once they're in a separate Github project, the `protop.json` file belongs at the root directory of the project.